# xset blank screen on idle not working (lubuntu)

Tags: screensaver, xset

I normally set the screen to go blank after N seconds, but after using the machine for a while, it stops working mysteriously.  It may be due to the `suspend` event.

Now I try:

```
xset s 2
```

and the screen won't blank after 2 (or more) seconds.

But this succeeds to blank the screen:

```
sleep 2; xset s activate
```

so it implies the blank screen function itself is normal.

Also, this prints the idle time correctly:

```
sleep 10; xprintidle
```

so it implies X is getting the idle time correctly.

I have removed `xfce4-power-manager` (and also exited the current process).

I'm not sure how to reproduce this, but it happens almost surely when I have my machine on for a long time (perhaps with suspension).

I will try to see if the first suspension is causing the problem.